# Removing leftovers from Symantec uninstallation

Tags: uninstall, symantec

I have uninstalled Symantec a long time ago, but there are still some leftovers remaining. Every time I start my computer, some dialogs will pop up and it's annoying.

There is no uninstallation entry in the Add/Remove program panel, so I cannot uninstall it using Windows tools.

I have downloaded the official Symantec removal tools, but the tool says that I have to first uninstall the software via Window's Add/Remove utility, which makes it a deadlock.

How do I clean these leftovers up?

Comment: Format. (please excuse the glib answer, but Symantec is hideous when it comes to removal)

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what product your are dealing with?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

[Use AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) to see if you can disable drivers or other Norton leftovers from the registry.

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but his question states that he downloaded the tool already _and it's not working_.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not specify the specific product, I'll give you two answers.

For Norton / retail products:

> ftp://ftp.symantec.com/public/english_us_canada/removal_tools/Norton_Removal_Tool.exe

For Symantec / corporate products:
You can call them and get an updated version of the [Cleanwipe](http://www.4shared.com/file/0lGjxHmk/CleanWipe.html) removal tool designed for this purpose. If THAT fails, there are detailed manual uninstall docs here:

> http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH104790
>
> http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH99631

Comment: +1 Have used the Cleanwipe tool and the previous iteration and both work well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use CCleaner to search the registry, then do a full file-system search for folders names Symantec, and then use Autoruns (from Sysinternals) to disable the start up entries and system services.

If that doesn't work, the other option is to download and install (preferably the same version of) Symantec again, then uninstall it. The install should bring together all the currently disconnected and orphaned parts and then make it easier to remove them using Uninstall.